# Adding CellImage from Google Sheets to a Google Doc using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to insert a CellImage taken from a Google Sheet into a newly created Google Doc using Apps Script.

I have a CellImage in a Google Sheet:
[A Google Sheet with an image created by the formula:

```
=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHz9s.png)
```

I've created an Apps Script that is supposed to create a new Google Doc and insert the image from cell A1 into the Doc:

```
function myFunction() {
  let doc = DocumentApp.create("QR Holder");
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let range = sheet.getRange("A1");
  let image = range.getValue();
  let url = image.getUrl();
  console.log(url);
  let blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  let body = doc.getBody();
  body.insertImage(0, blob);
}
```

Execution log

```
11:01:18 AM Notice  Execution started
11:01:21 AM Info    
11:01:20 AM Error   
Exception: Attribute provided with no value: url
myFunction  @ Code.gs:8
```

This shows that the url variable does not store a valid URL and the blob is not properly fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, the URL cannot be retrieved from `image` of `let image = range.getValue();` with `getUrl()`. In this case, it is required to retrieve the URL from the formulas retrieved with `getFormula`.
- In your sample image, it seems that the formula is `=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=...')"`. In this case, the last `)` might not be required to be used. But, I'm not sure whether this is your expected situation.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let image = range.getValue();
let url = image.getUrl();
```

#### To:

```
let url = encodeURI(range.getFormula().replace(/\=image\("(.*)"\)/i, "$1"));
```

#### Reference:

- [getFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula)