Is there a way to display an image in an HTML table directly from a Google Sheets cell?
I am having some difficulty displaying an image in an HTML table in a WebApp populated from Google Sheets data.  Yesterday, I created a post that was tagged as a duplicate to this post, but I believe a different solution is being requested.
My Google Sheets data looks like this:

In the cells webapp!B1:B I have images based on the forecast for the day.  The weather forecast is pulled from Visual Crossing data.  The formula logic is something like:

"if the forecast for today is "sunny", choose the picture in the cell
Icons!A1, else, if the forecast for today is "partly cloud", choose
the picture in the cell Icons!A2, etc."

The pictures to be displayed are "images in the cells" in Icons!A1:A.
My codes for the Webapp are below:
Code.gs
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}

function getSheetData()  { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('webapp'); 
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange();
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();  
  return dataValues;
}

HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css"
      />
      <style>
      .container {
        padding: 35px 7px 0px 7px;
         }
         
      .all-tables {
        font-size:16px;
        background-color: #EFEFEF;
        border: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 310px;
      }
      
      th, td {
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
      }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body class="container">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
  <style>
  body {
    font-family: "Poppins", serif;
  }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="all-tables">
    <?var tableData = getSheetData();?>
    <?for(var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) { ?>
      <?if(i == 0) { ?>
        <tr>
        <?for(var j = 0; j < tableData[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <th><?= tableData[i][j] ?></th>
        <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } else { ?>
        <tr>
        <?for(var j = 0; j < tableData[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= tableData[i][j] ?></td>
        <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>

The issue with the WebApp is that the images are not displayed.  Instead the image is replaced with "CellImage".  See the screenshot below:

I have tried replacing getValues() with getDisplayValues().  I have also tried changing the cell formatting in the cells webapp!B1:B.  In addition, I tried hosting the images on my Wordpress site and using  IMAGE() formula to get the image into the spreadsheet.  I also tried replacing the image with just the URL of the image.  This last change replaces "CellImage" with the URL but I still don't get the image in the WebApp.
Is this something that is possible?  The only other alternative I can think of is to try to use the solution from this aforementioned post and put the logic in the script itself that "if the forecast is sunny, choose the image at this URL, etc." but this approach seems much more convoluted to me.  Also, I am more versed in writing logic in a formula than in script .
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated and I apologize for the lengthy post.

Can you share with us a sample spreadsheet containing your input (first image)? Can you also clarify if the images are inside the cells? Or are the images over the cell?

"Images inside the cell".  I will have to make a sample spreadsheet.  Give me a little bit and I will add a link.

Sorry, I did try to improve my original post and point out that a different kind of solution is being requested.  I also voted to reopen the post, but to no avail.  I wrote a new post today and tried to re-phrase it to better show the distinction between the two questions.  Maybe I should have deleted yesterday's post?

@Wicket any advice on this?  Should I copy the content on this post and paste it into yesterday's post and delete this one?  Or should I delete yesterday's post?

I believe the previous duplicates were all linked incorrectly.    The closely related duplicates were https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75477392/adding-a-cellimage-from-one-google-sheet-to-another/75479421#75479421 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75343213/adding-cellimage-from-google-sheets-to-a-google-doc Nevertheless, I've made this the main question and reopened it.  The issue is CellImage's url cannot be accessed.

Images when added directly creates a unique publicly accessible url(security issue?) in  Google sheets. These urls are not accessible directly from apps script currently. The only way currently is to use =IMAGE("url") to get the images in sheet( which you stated you tried). If you do that, the external urls can be retrieved in Apps script using Range.getFormula().
Nevertheless, If you use an XLOOKUP to get the image, it is still not possible to get the url from the formula result cell without recreating the formula logic inside apps script.
However, one another way is to export the spreadsheet as xlsx and get the image data url from there, which is a complicated process, but Tanaike's DocsServiceApp library can be used to achieve this. See sample answer.  Once you have the data url, it can be used  directly in the anchor tag of html as data url

Thank you.  In regard to my question:  Is this something that is possible?  the following comment answers the question:  These urls are not accessible directly from apps script currently.  I will look into Tanaike's method as an alternative.
